# JQuery Document.ready functionality flashes at page start-up

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, document

I'm using JQuery's document.ready to hide some things from my MVC master page. When the page loads, though, I can see the elements that I'm removing flash for a second before disappearing.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#HideDiv").remove()
        });
    </script>
```

How can I get rid of that flashing? I want the elements that I'm removing gone before the page renders.

**Update:**

I should point out that I'm doing this dynamically, hiding certain things on certain pages. HideDiv was just an example name I gave, perhaps a poor one.

For example, I have a menu bar at the top that has links to various pages. I want to remove the link to a page when the user is on that page. Rather than manually adding only the wanted links on each page, I have them all in the master page, and I just hide the ones that I don't want shown on the page.

Apparently document.ready is not the time to do this? What might be a better way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the elements initally using CSS they will not be shown:

```
<style type="text/css">
#HideDiv { display: none; }
</style>
```

If that is not possible, you can put a script tag immediately after the element:

```
<div id="HdeDiv">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#HideDiv').remove();
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm hiding these things dynamically, based on the page. So I want HideDiv to show up on like 3 out of 10 pages.

Comment: @Mike - Maybe your solution can't be as generic as you want, then.

Answer (score 0):

instead of remove use fadeOut() or hide();

```
$("#HideDiv").remove(); // remove completly removes from dom
```

the below ones gives smooth effect

```
$("#HideDiv").fadeOut();

$("#HideDiv").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript will not run until the page has loaded - that's what $(document).ready() does.

But why not hide the div using css? Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #HideDiv
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```